# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS is taking forever to boot

Tags: boot, 16.04

I have been using this Ubuntu version for over 2 months. It used to boot very quickly (less than 15s).However, less than week ago it started to take more than 40s to boot (in the loading screen).

I looked up some discussions and I tried to analyze some logs that are recommended. I couldn't figure the problem by myself though.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Always to eliminate the simpler things first- have you designated any programs or services to autostart / start on boot, or the like?

Comment: I checked that. Apparently it is normal:  Dropbox (which never caused any issues) and those that look like system processes: GNOME Software (even though I use Unity), Indication Application, NVDIA X Server Settings, SSH Key Agent

Comment: Install (and set up and run) `bootchart`.  While booting, hit `/` and `Ctrl-Alt-F12` to see some startup messages.

Comment: @waltinator Well,  I installed it via apt-get. When I try to run on terminal I get:  "No path given, trying /var/log/bootchart.tgz
warning: path '/var/log/bootchart.tgz' does not exist, ignoring.
Parse error: empty state: '/var/log/bootchart.tgz' does not contain a valid bootchart". I have reinstalled and tried to do the key combination but it didn't work either.

Comment: run `systemd-analyze blame` as root to see which service takes the most time.

Comment: Does the Ubuntu run fine after boot? If everything is slow this could be a harddrive issue...

Comment: @spacelander I've done that. It looks normal to me. Those are the five most time consuming processes: 6.533s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          4.455s plymouth-start.service
          4.093s dev-sda7.device
          2.809s systemd-rfkill.service
          1.860s apparmor.service

Comment: @warhansen Yes, it works fine once the system loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave up. I had to no more time to keep searching for a solution so I reinstalled the system from scratch. 
I wish I could fix that but I was wasting too much time and work can't wait some times. 
It works fine now.